# break loop when empty string entered in C++

Tags: c++

I am taking a string input from the user. Following is my code

```
cout<<"enter the number of strings";
cin>>size;
int i=0;
while(i<size)
{
     string input="";
     cin.ignore();
     getline(cin,input);
     if(input.empty())
           break;
      i++;
}
```

I want to terminate the program when I give input as newline character (blank string). But above code runs for one extra counter. Where I am going wrong ?

Comment: Drop that stupid cin.ignore();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place cin.ignore outside the while, just before it

Here's the code

```
int main(){
    int size;
    cout<<"enter the number of strings";
    cin>>size;
    int i=0;
    cin.ignore();
     while(i < size)
    {
     string input="";
     getline(cin,input);
     if(input == "")
           break;
      i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Already tested on my side, and it works. I'm sorry I cannot give you more detail, it's been a while since I coded C++

Comment: Again, I'm not sure, I was testing and it works. I haven't coded in C++ in a long time. But I tested it. And @πάνταῥεῖ if it works, it should not be a comment, comments are mainly for questions to expand the issue understanding

Comment: You have _πάνταῥεῖ'd it_?!? That **needs** more explanation ;)! So if you have tested and running code, why not just posting the sample here? The OP themselves are asking for it ...

Comment: I did research, cin.ignore() ignores the new line character. Everytime the while passed to getline if this guy pressed enter it was leaving a newline character. C++ understood it as to "wait until I write anything else than a new character" http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/9148/

Comment: @PlaceUserNameHere Released the downvote (and gave an upvote even) ... Yes! Now you have **you have** _πάντα ῥεῖ'd it_, accepted! :D ...

Answer (score 4):

The `getline()` function returns data including the carriage return, so your input isn't going to actually be empty when a "blank line" is provided.

```
DESCRIPTION
     The getdelim() function reads a line from stream, delimited by the char-
     acter delimiter.  The getline() function is equivalent to getdelim() with
     the newline character as the delimiter.  The delimiter character is
     included as part of the line, unless the end of the file is reached.
```

Note also that the function returns the number of characters written to your buffer... you can simply check for that value rather than calling `input.empty()`, and at the same time you could perform error checking.

Comment: what modification needs to be done to get a expected behaviour?

Comment: `if (getline(...) < 2) break;` should do it; this will terminate the loop on errors and when the input is only a single character (the carriage return).